# Is there any relation between cdfs as in set theory?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

This might be a silly question, but I could not find any useful information about it. Take two uniform distributions, $F\sim\mathcal{U}(-1,2)$ and $F^{\prime}\sim\mathcal{U}(0,2)$. Is there some special definiton/name for these kind of relations? Although they are different distributions, support of $F^{\prime}$ is a subset of support of $F$

Comment: I would suggest that you expand this question with more details and perhaps examples, so we can get a better sense of what you're asking.

Comment: I think this is much more clear now.

Comment: By CDF do you mean PDF? The support of a CDF is never interesting.